# Why can't I use this C program without defining an extra variable?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int remainder,number,sum=0,temp;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    temp=number;

    while(temp!=0)
    {
        remainder=temp%10;
        sum=sum+pow(remainder,3);
        temp=temp/10;
    }

    if(sum==number)
    {
        printf("armstrong number");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not an armstrong number");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to create an armstrong number checker for 3 digits number . I am using turbo C latest , compiler . This code goes to **else** and does not work for armstrong number 371. Meanwhile,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    int remainder,number,sum=0,temp,cube=0;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter any number\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);

    temp=number;

    while(temp!=0)
    {
        remainder=temp%10;
        cube=pow(remainder,3);
        sum=sum+cube;
        temp=temp/10;
    }

    if(sum==number)
    {
        printf("armstrong number");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("not an armstrong number");
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Look carefully in the second code I have added a new variable **cube** and changed the formula to 
 **cube=pow(remainder,3); 
sum=sum+cube;** 
 and suddenly the program works for all 3 digit armstrong numbers . Please help me understand what I am doing wrong in first code . Thanks.

Comment: Please format your code with proper indentation.  It is difficult to read like this.

Comment: Why are you using Turbo C instead of a compiler from this century? Is this a limitation you can't avoid?

Comment: Since `pow` is a function for `double` but you use it for `int`, I suspect that you have round-off errors.

Comment: Instead of `pow` why not `remainder*remainder*remainder`? The `pow` function is really overkill here.

Comment: You are right , I usually use codeblocks but for some reason that was very buggy and slow in my PC so I installed Turbo C. Nevertheless , So is the compiler at fault or am I ?

Comment: [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com) is probably a good place to start unless you want something really stripped down. Turbo C is extremely antiquated and not really a useful learning tool unless you want to learn how primitive C development was in the 1990s. If you want something more minimal, with [Linux on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) you can get GCC or clang and do it all command-line style.

Comment: Post _real_ code; `return0;` is not valid.  _"Look carefully ..."_; if you want people to look at your code, it is polite to use conventional formatting.  "_Turbo C latest compiler_" - that is very funny - that will be version 2.0 from 1988 then!?

Comment: tadman,Osiris thanks . dbush , man I am new here okay ? anyways what is the better way to format code while posting in forums here on stackoverflow ?

Comment: It's not only about formatting code when posting here, it's about making a habit of always formatting it, so that one can see the structure of it immediately. Indent with every opening brace; unindent with every closing brace.

Comment: Each new logical level should be indented at least 4 spaces in from the prior level.  That's not just for here, but **anytime** you write code.

Comment: You have missed the point; posting code on SO you should use code mark-up as you have, but the code you posted did not have conventional formatting - i.e. it was not indented to show structure.  Never mind; I have fixed it for you.

Answer (score 4):

The `pow` function takes a `double` for each of its arguments and returns a double, so what it does under the hood is more than simple repeated multiplication.  The resulting value could be slightly bigger or slightly smaller than the actual result, and if it's slightly smaller you end up with a truncated result when it gets converted back to `int`.  For example if `pow(5, 3)` returns ~124.99999, the result will get truncated to 124.

Since you're only cubing each number, just do the multiplication explicitly to avoid this issue:

```
sum += remainder * remainder * remainder;
```

Comment: Maybe it is also worth to mention that the difference in OPs code is due to the fact that in the first example at the additon `sum` was promoted to `double` while in the second example `pow` was converted to `int` (due to variable assignment).